# 3rd party package installation on Groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to install a joystick package in my ROS Groovy system.

I followed the tutorial I found in ROS wiki ([www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/StackInstallation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/StackInstallation)) but it seems to be a bit outdated, because at a certain moment (after the git cloning of the project in /opt/ros/groovy/share directory) it says to do a "rosmake --rosdep-install", something that gives me an error: rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install

I believe I have to install the package using catkin but I am getting errors too: The specified base path "/opt/ros/groovy/share/joystick_drivers/joy" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace

I wonder if I have to create another workspace since I already have the one I created for the beginner_tutorials?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70186/3rd-party-package-installation-on-groovy/) by [hsmptg](https://answers.ros.org/users/5680/hsmptg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by instaling the package using apt-get: sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers
But nevertheless I would like to know how to compile/install the package from the source code I got from the git repository.

---

Originally posted by [hsmptg](https://answers.ros.org/users/5680/hsmptg/) with karma: 16 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0